# Kotlin Flows declaration in Compose function

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-flow, koin

In my task I need to fetch list of bikes.

I made BikesApi and put some bikes into a list.
In MovieRepository implementation I overrided function getBikes that returns now Flow<List>>.

```
val BikeZ : Flow<List<Bike>> = flow{
            while(true){
                val lastBikeX = bikeApi.getBikes()
                emit(lastBikeX)
                kotlinx.coroutines.delay(1000)
            }
        }
        return BikeZ
```

In BikeViewModel I implemented it like this, It gets MovieRepository (Koin):

```
public fun getPopularBikes() = flow<Bike> {
    val bikesList = repository.getPopularBikes().collect()
    return@flow bikesList
}
```

And when I try in Compose function this:

```
 val viewModel = viewModel<BikeViewModel>()
```

I got this error:
Cannot create an instance of class BikeViewModel.

> ```
> java.lang.RuntimeException:
> ```
>
> Cannot create an instance of class BikeViewModel

I'm using Koin.
I need list of Movies to implement them into UI.

EDIT:
In app module i did this:

```
single<BikeApi>{
BikeApiImpl()
}


 single<BikeRepository>{
        BikeRepositoryImpl(get())
    }
  viewModel { BikeViewModel(get()) }
```

Bike api:

```
class BikeApiImpl : BikeApi{
    override suspend fun getPopularBikes():  List<Bike> {
        return listOf(
            Bike(
                id = 1,
                name = "Nakamura",
                isCheckedOff = true,
                bikeType = "MTB",
                overview = "None",
                picture = R.drawable.nakamura_1,
                userScore = 72.0
        )
```

I't wont return list of Bikes.

Comment: This error has nothing to do with either the Flow or Compose. It literally means that your ViewModel class doesn't have a zero argument constructor.

Comment: BikeViewModel has MovieRepo in Constructor is that issue ?

Comment: yes, if you're using Hilt, make sure your view model has `@HiltViewModel` annotation, as well as `@Inject` annotation for your constructor. If you don't use Hilt, how do you expect your repo to be injected?

Comment: Via constructor initialization!! I solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your `viewModel` like this if you are using Koin di:

```
val viewModel: BikeViewModel by viewModel()
```

also import

```
import org.koin.androidx.viewmodel.ext.android.viewModel
```

Comment: Not working it says;     java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast to androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel

Comment: @Equlo post your complete code

Comment: Posted BikeApi, currently I need to implement it without Room db.